# Is there a way to ignore JSHint warning for multiple warning?

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

I am working on node.js application and using gulp for JSLint and want to ignore some express.js key words like (require, export, process etc).

How I can igore this in gulp file.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that JSLint has a "Node.js" option that you can set so it will allow those keywords (ah, there it is: https://github.com/karimsa/gulp-jslint/blob/98594eb29d550bee7d421eb4c5465382cfa25171/gulpfile.js#L23)

Comment: JSLint has `--ignore` option.